# Problem with tab index after closing one of the tabs in gwt

Tags: gwt, tabs, indexing

I am developing a application in GWT using the [decorated tab panel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedTabPanel.html). I have implemented a close option for the tabs. Now my problem is that when I close one tab and try to add some data in the other tab it is taking the wrong index.

For example: I have 4 tabs and close the third one. I open 4th tab and try to add something there, but its index is showing as 3 instead of 4 as there are only 3.

How can I reset the tab index in the program, or else any solution where I can read the correct index of tab as it was before removing it?

This is where i am adding the new tab and the close event.

```
HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
Image image = new Image();
Label label = new Label("New Report: " + k);
label.setWordWrap(false);

horizontalPanel.add(label);
horizontalPanel.add(image);

image.setUrl("images/1305803163_close.png");
tabpanel.add(newTab[k], horizontalPanel);
tabindexx[k] = k;

image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    tabpanel.remove(tabpanel.getTabBar().getSelectedTab());
  }
});
```

and in some part of the code I am accessing the tab index like this

```
int selectedtab = tabpanel.getTabBar().getSelectedTab();
```

Of course this will return an index based on the number of tabs present at that particular moment, so I need to store them somewhere or else I have to reset the tab index after I close.

Comment: The tab panel uses 0-based indexing, so index 3 is really the forth element, as the tabs would be numbered 0-1-2-3, but maybe that's just a typo in your example... Could you maybe post some code to make your question a little clearer?

Comment: Don't post the code in a comment, add it to your question by pressing the "edit" link under the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

That will happen because the index number is the index for the current set of tabs. (if one closes, it obviously impacts the others).

I am a little rusty with GWT now, but i believe the only way to remove or select tabs is using index.

One solution could be to manage a List of tab representatives (some tab identifier) in your code, and do a mirror remove in that list when a delete occurs in your code. Then you can lookup the new index of the tab that you want to update after the delete and get the right index. (Tab identifier can be as simple as the original index of the tab when you started before any deletes)